# how do i convert a c# style regular expression to c++ style

Tags: c++, regex

I was trying to parse a lengthy string through a regular expression, i tried doing it with the following RE and text mentioned at this link http://regexr.com/3a7uf

But when I try to parse the text in c++ using the same RE, the compile time warnings and output not as expected.

Please advise how to get this RE sorted into a format so that it becomes possible to parse text, in a C++ program.

The code goes like this:

```
std::string str = "root     21015  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    "
    "16:07   0:00 [kworker/5:0]\n            root     21095  0.0  0.0  "
    "    0     0 ?        S    16:08   0:00 [kworker/2:2]\n            "
    "root     21097  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    16:08   0:00 ["
    "kworker/u16:4]\n            ashish   21103 17.1  1.2 591536 106056"
    " ?       Sl   16:12   0:01 /usr/lib/firefox/firefox";

std::regex firefox ("[0-9].\..*.firefox");

std::smatch sm;
std::regex_match (str, sm, firefox);
std::cout << "number of matches: " << sm.size() << std::endl;

std::cout << "matches were: " << std::endl;
for (unsigned int i = 0; i < sm.size(); i++)
{
    std::cout << "[" << sm[i] << "]";
}
```

---

***warning during compilation as follows:***

```
warning: unknown escape sequence: '\\.'
     regex firefox ("[0-9].\\..*.firefox");
```

---

***output is as follows:***

```
number of matches: 0

matches were:
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the replies. There was nothing wrong with the expression itself.

I just used the following syntax to create the regular expression and it worked well.

```
std::regex otherProcessRegEx ("[0-9][0-9][:.:].*.[a-z].|[0-9][:.:].*.[a-z]",
               std::regex_constants::ECMAScript |     
               std::regex_constants::icase);
```

with c++ 11 were introduced these http://www.johndcook.com/blog/cpp_regex/ different types of RegEx, which were needed to be specified.

:)

Answer (score 3):

You need to use [double escapes](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/escape) here.

```
[0-9].\\..*.firefox
```

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Answer (score 1):

This looks to me to just be an issue with the way strings are dealt with. You can try

```
std::regex firefox (@"[0-9].\..*.firefox");
```

To indicate that it is a string literal, or if that syntax isn't supported try

```
std::regex firefox ("[0-9].\\..*.firefox");
```

Which is saying you really want a `\` character in the string, not an escaped period.

#### Edit

From the comment below, it appears as though the C# syntax was not correct, or the periods were meant to concatenate (like PHP?), however they do not concatenate in regular expressions, [they are placeholders](http://www.regular-expressions.info/dot.html).

```
std::regex firefox ("[0-9]+[.][0-9]+[^.]*firefox");
```

Could you highlight what you want to match, exactly (start to finish), in the sample above? I can't really tell where you want the matching to start, but if you're trying to find numbers and periods, the above would start at the `1.2`.

Comment: hi Ehryk.. Thanks for reply, Iwas looking forward to not read the backslash from string, rather I wanted it to find the dot for which i have used "\." so that it doesn't use the dot char for concatenation but actually tries to find it in the given string.

Comment: Oh, then use a character class. Dots don't concatenate, either, they're a place holder. I'll edit my answer.

Answer (score 1):

You're going to have to escape your backslashes for them to be valid C++ strings.  For instance, try:

```
std::regex firefox ("[0-9].\\..*.firefox");
```